# How to noindex for certain custom post type without using plugins..?

Tags: custom-post-types, noindex

Is there a way to create a noindex (meta robot ) for certain custom post type that i have for my wordpress blog..? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Go in your `header.php` and add the following snippet where you want your tag to appear:

```
<?php 
if( 'your-post-type' === get_post_type() ){
  print '<META NAME="ROBOTS" CONTENT="NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW">';
}
?>
```

[`get_post_type()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_type) will return the current post type.

Comment: Note that `get_post_type()` will simply retrieve type of current post, without checking what kind of page in hierarchy it is (single/archive/etc).

Comment: Do you think that something like [`is_singular('post-type')`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_singular) would have been better here?

Comment: Question does not specify enough details to say which condition would fit best, just noted for other people so they are aware of it when making use of answer.